# What is the $\boldsymbol{l_{1,q}}$ norm (with comma)?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I can find information about $\boldsymbol{l_1}$-norm or $\boldsymbol{l_2}$-norm. But what is $\boldsymbol{l_{1,2}}$-norm (or $\boldsymbol{l_{1,q}}$-norm)? May you give me a source to read or explain regarding this statement as an example?

"The $\boldsymbol{l_{1,q}}$-norm of a matrix is the sum of vector $\boldsymbol{l_q}$-norms of its rows. Penalization with $\boldsymbol{l_{1,q}}$-norm promotes as many number of zero rows as possible to appear in $\boldsymbol{Y}$ (for the $\boldsymbol{l_{1,q}}$-norm of $\boldsymbol{Y}$ )"

Comment: The statement you provided actually seems fairly clear. Can you elaborate on what you don't understand about it?

Comment: @littleO I am unsure what is _q_ here. I reread this statement but still can't visualize. What is _l1,q_ called? So I can search more sources to read about.

Comment: I don't know of any name for it other than just $\ell_{1,q}$-norm (although sometimes the $1$ and the $q$ are reversed). One keyword though is "group sparsity". People penalize the $\ell_{1,2}$-norm to promote group sparsity.

Comment: @littleO Ok. So here, does it mean in each row of $\boldsymbol{Y}$, do $\boldsymbol{l_{q}}$ norm and sum all the row together? It is not $\boldsymbol{l_1}$-norm but the "$\boldsymbol{_{1}}$" is just for telling it is calculated by row?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Compute the $\ell_q$ -norm of each row, then add them all up. A slightly different way to say it is that you can compute the $\ell_{1,q}$-norm of a matrix $Y$ in two steps: 1) Compute the vector $v$ whose $i$th component is the $\ell_q$-norm of the $i$th row of $Y$; 2) compute the $\ell_1$-norm of $v$.  The number you get when you do those two steps is the $\ell_{1,q}$-norm of $Y$.  The fact that the second step uses the $\ell_1$-norm helps to explain the term $\ell_{1,q}$-norm.